# How do you calculate the load on a nvidia (cuda capable), gpu card?

Tags: c++, cuda, hardware, gpu, nvidia

I want to know how to display percentage of the graphics card ability upon tasks being sent to the card. Like a Gnome's system monitor.

Moreover, how to obtain device parameters to calculate a percentage based on its hardware specs

How does `nvidia-smi -a` get utilization? Is there an Cuda API to ask the card for this information?

Answer (score 6):

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) does this (this is only for Windows), but it's not CUDA-specific.

I know it uses some undocumented functions -- take a look at [the plugin's source code](http://processhacker.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/processhacker/2.x/trunk/plugins/ExtendedTools/gpumon.c?revision=4927&view=markup) to find out how.

[image]

Comment: Note that this appears to only work on Windows 7+ according to the source-code. Either way, the undocumented function would be "D3DKMTQueryStatistics" from GDI32.dll and you'd need to get your hands on d3dkmt.h (google it) for structure definitions.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is not done in CUDA. For a percentage output of the utilization handles by a specific cuda device you have to ask the GPU driver like nvidia-smi does.

**EDIT:** After a little google search i found [open-hardware-monitor](http://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/) It is written in C# and shows a way to get the utilization of AMD and nVidia cards on windows systems. The implementation for AMD cards works on linux and windows.

I've looked a bit inside the code. Look at the NVAPI.cs file to see how open-hardware-monitor uses the nvidia dlls on windows to get all sensor and load data.