# How to query GPU Usage in DirectX?

Tags: graphics, directx, direct3d

How to query GPU Usage in DirectX? Specifically DirectX 11.
If someone ever did it, could you provide me the code snippet?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to do? U can use visual studio to profile the gpu and capture frames if this is what you need.

Comment: Here -> http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=325 D3DKMTQueryStatistics is used. Not sure what they mean with ExtendedTools (see the last postings)

Answer (score 5):

[Process Hakcer](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) is able to do this. See here: http://processhacker.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/processhacker/2.x/trunk/plugins/ExtendedTools/gpumon.c?revision=4927&view=markup

A similar question has been asked here: [How do you calculate the load on a nvidia (cuda capable), gpu card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418489/how-do-you-calculate-the-load-on-a-nvidia-cuda-capable-gpu-card)